# Uninitialized constant when running rake commands in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am trying to follow this tutorial http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html.
When I run rake db:migrate, I get

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateArticles
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:762:in `load_migration'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:757:in `migration'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1045:in `use_transaction?'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `rescue in block in migrate'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `block in migrate'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/nbandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've spent the past four hours looking through answers but none of them have helped. I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to this, so I'm sure the answer is more obvious than I think. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following files and how the naming is done. The convention should be:

/models/article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
...
```

/db/migrate/20140625123456_create_articles.rb

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
...
```

Comment: There is a step which asked to copy and paste into the migration file, and I pasted over the text in your post. Thanks!